# How to close programs in the Android-x86 emulator?

Tags: applications, android-x86, virtualbox

This may seem like an odd question but I cannot resolve it. I am using the Android-x86 emulator in VirtualBox (https://www.android-x86.org/documentation/virtualbox.html). I open various apps like Firefox, Chrome, Maps, etc.

Normally, I would click the 'x' or go to a menu which said 'exit'. But there is nothing like that. Swiping the app up / down / left / right does nothing. I use "Force Stop" in Settings but that doesn't close the program. In Ubuntu, I can `ps aux | grep program_name` and then kill the PID. But `ps aux` does not work in the Android Terminal.

How can I close those apps? Can I use the terminal to close programs?

Comment: I don't know about Android-x86 but on common Android devices, pressing the back button until it navigates to the home screen is the way to close the app. Also, "force stopping" the app should close the app. Do you see any counter-evidence that says otherwise?

Comment: @AndrewT - the counter-evidence for "force stop" not working is that the program (e.g. Firefox) does not close. That said, I have the same issue on Kindle Fire which also uses Android. However, when I power off the KIndle, the apps are not running when I turn it on. Whereas, in the x86 emulator, the apps are all running on start-up after power off.

Comment: "*Whereas, in the x86 emulator, the apps are all running on start-up after power off.*" does this happen only after booting/restarting the Android, or the VirtualBox?

Answer (score 3):

If you view the currently open apps, you can hold click on the bottom of the app preview window and drag up to close the application.

This took me a while to figure out myself.

Comment: This was a top hit for hard to swipe away close apps on android emulator on mac.  Something about using the touch pad on my macbook I am guessing something happens at the end of the gesture preventing it from treating it as a swipe away.

Comment: @MathiasTCK, try to grab the swipe from the bottom of the app card and then swipe it all the way up the screen. It is a little bit odd how hard it is to accomplish that on the simulator.